# Unable to get sum to print in outfile

Tags: python, file, loops, sum, output

I am attempting to create a program that will sum corresponding values in separate lists and write a new file with the calculated sum. For example, I have `infile_1.txt` with 10 items and `infile_2.txt` also with 10 items. The goal is to take the first number from `infile_1.txt`, add it to the first number of `infile_2` and create a new text file with the sum of the two numbers. The two files are in the same folder as my program, so Python recognizes them and prints the new file to the folder as well. The code I am using is below:

```
def sumen():
outfile = input("Name the output file: ")
myfile_1 = open("infile_1.txt",'r')
myfile_2 = open("infile_2.txt",'r')
outputfile = open(outfile, 'w')
for line in myfile_1:
    readfile1 = myfile_1.readline()
    readfile2 = myfile_2.readline()
    totalenergy = myfile_1[0:] + myfile_2[0:]
    print(totalenergy,file=outputfile)
myfile_1.close()
myfile_2.close()
outputfile.close()
sumen()
```

When I run the program it allows me to choose the outfile (`totalenergy.txt`), and then it ends. I've checked the file that Python creates and there is nothing written in it.

Currently, I am experiencing the error "*totalenergy = myfile_1[0:] + myfile_2[0:]
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable*". I've also encountered an Attribute Error that had to do with the closing of the infiles and the outfile that said " *'str' has no attribute 'close'* "

One additional question: If the two files differ in length, is it possible to rewrite the for loop to account for the difference in length? Another thing I'm wondering about is if the line `totalenergy = myfile_1[0:] + myfile_2[0:]`is correct in the sense of Python grabbing the next value in each list during each consecutive iteration.

I am relatively new at python, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `for line in myfile_1:`, that reads the file, so `myfile_1.readline()` gets the *next* line. You don't need the second statement.

Also, `readfile1` and `readfile2` will be strings. If you want to add them as integers, you need to call `int()` to convert them.

```
for readfile1 in myfile_1:
    readfile2 = myfile_2.readline()
    totalenergy = int(readfile1) + int(readfile2)
    print(totalenergy,file=outputfile)
```

See [How to cleanly loop over two files in parallel in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830552/how-to-cleanly-loop-over-two-files-in-parallel-in-python) for other ways to write this loop.

Comment: Also note that, depending on Python version, mixing iteration and explicit calls to `.readline()` is not safe, and won't necessarily work properly. Just iterate (implicitly with loops or explicitly via `next(myfile_1)`), don't also call `.readline()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Is it really unsafe when they're different files?

Comment: Ah, missed it was two different files, that's safe. Of course, `for readfile1, readfile2 in zip(myfile_1, myfile_2):` would accomplish iterating in parallel more directly anyway.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Mixing iteration and readline was the problem in his original code. And one of the answers in the question I linked to shows how to use `zip()` or `izip()`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much for the fast response! I tested the code after making the adjustments and it worked